# Can I saturate a BC337 transistor using the output from a 4017 decade counter?

Tags: transistors, led, power-electronics, shift-register

I want to build something very similar to an 8x8 led matrix (like this one https://www.instructables.com/810-LED-Matrix-with-4017/ only with more power) using a shift register plus eight transistors to supply the electricity and a 4017 decade counter with eight BC337 transistors drain it (switching between the eight rows really fast).

I think that the maximum current which needs to be able to flow through the BC337 transistor would be 500 mA (it can handle 800 mA maximum).

If I understand correctly, the datasheet of the BC337 states that 50 mA is required in order to saturate it so that it would work as a switch.

Does anyone know if the 4017 counter would be able to supply this and what kind of resistor I would need to use?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! What does the 4017 datasheet tell you?

Comment: i read the datasheet but i could not make sense of it. this is the link to the 4017 datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4017b.pdf?ts=1601976866059&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD4017B%253FHQS%253DTI-null-null-alldatasheets-df-pf-SEP-wwe%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526dclid%253DCIL9ju3Un-wCFUGTewodb9UDXQ

Comment: and the BC337 transistor: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/BC337-D.PDF

Comment: honestly i also have a very limited understanding of the workings of voltage and current. except I = V / R. but that is in a closed circuit where V is the voltage drop. I found the information i found on how this would work with transistors rather confusing.

Comment: @bigpapi that formula applies to resistors only (hence the R); if this is your current state of understanding, chances are very high you misread the BC337 datasheet. let me check.

Comment: No, you're right. That's a terrible transistor. Get any NPN transistor that has higher current gain. this problem is easy if you don't use the oldest transistors one can still buy.

Comment: by the way, an LED with a forward of 500 mA is **bright** as in **working light bright**. make sure you actually want that.

Comment: so, I had a look at your instructable: this won't work for high currents, at all, since the current for the LEDs comes out of a logic gate and hence is very limited. You'd need to re-design the whole thing, at which point the instructable ceases to be useful

Comment: thanks, i also wanted to switch transistors using the shift registers in order to supply the electricity to the leds for that reason. not directly from the shift register. i bought the transistors a while back from aliexpress without much regard for quality.

Comment: To switch 500 mA you should not use the BC337 as it will have a low current amplification at such a high current. There are "smarter" solutions these days like using an N-channel MOSFET. I would use the AO3400, these are small SMD N-ch MOSFETs, can handle very high currents and are cheap. But SMD so a pain to solder.

Comment: @bigpapi Re: buying random components: this isn't about quality (Ok, it also is, because I generally consider transistors from aliexpress as worthless – there's a reason they landed there, and that usually is that they did not go through, or failed, quality control at one of the larger factories), but simply about buying the wrong thing: If you go to a hardware store and buy M8 nuts, but need M5 nuts, then no matter how high-quality the M8 nuts are, they're not what you need. Same here. For the high-side switching, you'll need something else altogether, and for the low-side these are wrong.

Comment: I agree with @Bimpelrekkie: go for MOSFETs (or at least "prebiased" BJT transistors which contain resistors and everything and are meant exactly for the use case of using logic to switch higher currents). I'm not afraid about you having to use SMD components at all: you're probably relatively young, you might have steady hands that learning to deal with this is easy for you, and SOT-23 packages (like the one Bimpelrekkie recommended) are large enough to be hand-soldered onto standard 2.54mm-pitch breadboard.

Comment: @bigpapi Doing a circuit like that in a perfboard is so difficult, and the resulting board is always awful. For that Instructable, I don't understand why its author used a perfboard; I bet he had more hours of dull work with that perfboard than if he had designed a PCB. I would suggest you to try to learn how to design your own PCB, and have it made at a factory; or, better: make it yourself using the tonner transfer method (it is not so difficult; the result is far from a industrial board, but I think that it is very "rewarding" for a "maker"). This is an art that seems to be fading.

Comment: thanks for all the quick comments guys, i am looking at SMD N-ch MOSFETs right now and indeed they are very cheap even with maximum currents well above what i will be using. I will definitely buy some of those. @Bimpelrekkie.